# Start a external program at pre-start in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote a program which packs my resources into a file, and that should happen before I'm starting my main program. How can I start that program, before my main program starts(e.g. by clicking on "Debug" or "Start" in Visual Studio)?

Comment: You plan on starting the program only from the IDE. Should the packaging happen before you, say, double-click the exe?

Comment: No, only from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the **Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging**, you can edit the **Command** section and add your program.

Comment: I tried that, but then my main program won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Although answer by [Luchian Grigore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828973/1607442) is perfectly fine, there are few alternatives to consider:

- If you need to pack your resources only once on build, but not every time debugger starts, you can add "Build Events" or "Custom build steps" (see project options).
- You can add another project to solution, and make main project depend on it. It can be Makefile project, so you can do whatever you want on build
- You can spawn your resource packer process directly from C++ code (probably only in debug mode, by using conditional compilation)